# How to insert array to the BD Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.7

I have a consult, I need to insert an array that I get from `foreach` of the view, but at the moment of doing the requests in the controller I get that all the values ​​are null.

view

```
@foreach($product as $prod)
<tr>
    <td>                                            
        <input  type ="text" name="name[]" value="{{ $prod->name}}" readonly="readonly">
    </td>
    <td>                                           
        <input type="text" name="price[]" class="price" value="{{ $prod->price}}" readonly="readonly">
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="number" min="1" max="100" class="quantity" value="1" name="quantity[]">
    </td>
</tr>

@endforeach
```

Controller

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    for($i=0;$i<=2;$i++){
        $detail= new Detail;
        $detail->name= $request->input('name['.$i.']');
        $detail->quantity= $request->input('quantity['.$i.']');
        $detail->price= $request->input('price['.$i.']');
        $detail->created_at = Carbon::now();
        $detail->updated_at = Carbon::now();
        $detail->save();
   }

   return redirect()->route('view')->with('success','Exit');
}
```

The values ​​name, price and quantity return me null values.

**The result of dd($request) returned the correct values of the array**

Comment: Please add a `dd($request)` result in your question then I can help you better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something just like this can help you

```
$input = $request->all();

    for($i=1; $i<= count($input['quantity']); $i++) {

      $data = [ 
        'name' => $input['name'][$i],
        'price' => $input['price'][$i],
        'quantity' => intval($input['quantity'][$i])
      ];

      Detail::create($data);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I do not know why it did not work in other ways but with this syntax yes.

Comment: You are welcome man. I have a similar problem with warehouse project.

Answer (score 0):

`for` loop in controller should look something like below:
I have created an array to store data and then batch insert the whole array.

```
$now = Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString();
$data = [];
for($i= 0; $i <= 2; $i++){
    $data[] = [
        'created_at'=>$now, 
        'updated_at'=>$now,
        'name' => $request->input("name[$i]"), //changed quotes type. 
        'price= $request->input("price[$i]")
        /* similar for other fields....*/

    ];
}

Detail::insert($data);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but when inserting the data, they remain null.

Comment: I have edited the answer. please try the updated code.